# iOS app targeting 8 with an intent extension crashes in the simulator

Tags: ios

- I have an iOS app that targets iOS 8.
- It includes an Intent Extension (for Siri Shortcuts).
- It runs perfectly fine on iOS 12 (device + simulator) and 10 (simulator).
- It crashes immediately in the iOS 8 simulator and outputs the following:

---

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/Intents.framework/Intents
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator
```

---

I realize that I won't be able to use the Intents Extension on older versions of iOS, but I still want my main app to work. From what I've read online, I should still be able to target 8 even though I use SiriKit. Any Intent related code has been guarded against when iOS < 12.

My project is configured like this:

- Project Deployment Target: 8.0
- Main App Deployment Target: 8.0
- Intents Extension Deployment Target: 12.0

I have tested some things to try to figure out what exactly is causing the problem:

- Removing all my Intents related code in the main app => Does not work
- Removing the Intent Extension target => Does not work
- Removing the Intent Definition File => Works

Is this an issue with Xcode/Simulator or a bug in my application?

Comment: Any updates on this issue ?

Comment: @MehulParmar Unfortunately no. I created a TSI with Apple, and they just told me to file a bug report (which I did). I doubt this will ever get fixed though.

Comment: @pqvst I could really use your help. I cannot get my obj-c implementation of a custom intent to work. The intent handler is not being called. You are the only person I have seen that has documented a working version of this in obj-c. Could you please have a look? I have detailed my implementation in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70177084/custom-intent-handler-not-called-ios-claims-intenthandlermethodforintent-not-i